# 'result_type': is not a member of '`Traits'::Less_xy_2'

Tags: compiler-errors, traits, cgal, convex-hull

I was trying to compute the convex hull of a set of 2D points using CGAL. I wanted to define my own *Traits* class trying to follow the CGAL [ConvexHullTraits_2 Concept Reference](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Convex_hull_2/classConvexHullTraits__2.html). I report the code I wrote:

```
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/convex_hull_2.h>
#include <CGAL/convex_hull_traits_2.h>

using namespace std;

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef K::Point_2 Point_2;
typedef pair<Point_2, unsigned> Point_with_info;
typedef CGAL::Convex_hull_traits_2<K> DefaultTraits;

class NewTraits
{
public:

    typedef Point_with_info Point_2;

    class Equal_2
    {
    public:
        bool operator()(Point_2 p, Point_2 q)
        {
            return DefaultTraits::Equal_2()(p.first, q.first);
        }
    };

    class Less_xy_2
    {
    public:
        bool operator()(Point_2 p, Point_2 q)
        {
            return DefaultTraits::Less_xy_2()(p.first, q.first);
        }
    };

    class Less_yx_2
    {
    public:
        bool operator()(Point_2 p, Point_2 q)
        {
            return DefaultTraits::Less_yx_2()(p.first, q.first);
        }
    };

    class Left_turn_2
    {
    public:
        bool operator()(Point_2 p, Point_2 q, Point_2 r) const
        {
            return DefaultTraits::Left_turn_2()(p.first, q.first, r.first);
        }
    };

    class Less_signed_distance_to_line_2
    {
    public:
        bool operator()(Point_2 p, Point_2 q, Point_2 r, Point_2 s)
        {
            return DefaultTraits::Less_signed_distance_to_line_2()(p.first, q.first, r.first, s.first);
        }
    };

    class Less_rotate_ccw_2
    {
    public:
        bool operator()(Point_2 e, Point_2 p, Point_2 q)
        {
            return DefaultTraits::Less_rotate_ccw_2()(e.first, p.first, q.first);
        }
    };

    class Orientation_2
    {
    public:
        CGAL::Orientation operator()(Point_2 e, Point_2 p, Point_2 q)
        {
            return DefaultTraits::Orientation_2()(e.first, p.first, q.first);
        }
    };

    NewTraits(NewTraits &t) {};
    NewTraits() {};

    Equal_2 equal_2_object() const
    {
        return Equal_2();
    }

    Less_xy_2 less_xy_2_object() const
    {
        return Less_xy_2();
    }

    Less_yx_2 less_yx_2_object() const
    {
        return Less_yx_2();
    }

    Less_signed_distance_to_line_2 less_signed_distance_to_line_2_object()
    {
        return Less_signed_distance_to_line_2();
    }

    Less_rotate_ccw_2 less_rotate_ccw_2_object()
    {
        return Less_rotate_ccw_2();
    }

    Left_turn_2 left_turn_2_object() const
    {
        return Left_turn_2();
    }

    Orientation_2 orientation_2_object() const
    {
        return Orientation_2();
    }
};

typedef vector<Point_with_info> Set_of_points_with_info;

int main()
{
    Set_of_points_with_info points;
    Set_of_points_with_info result;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        points.push_back(make_pair(Point_2(i, i), i));
    }

    CGAL::convex_hull_2(points.begin(), points.end(), back_inserter(result), NewTraits());

    return 0;
}
```

If I compile the above code, I get the following error:

```
Error C2039    'result_type': is not a member of 'NewTraits::Less_xy_2'
```

I could fix the compilation error by adding `typedef K::Less_xy_2::result_type result_type;` to the class `NewTraits::Less_xy_2`.

My questions are:

- Is this the right way to fix the issue?
- Why am I supposed to add this member even if documentation doesn't say it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Yes, the fix is correct.
- You are supposed to add `result_type` for a back-compatibility reason. In fact,  `NewTraits::Less_xy_2` is a binary predicate, hence a functor. After the adoption of C++11 standard, this addition would not be necessary, since from that revision was introduced, for the same purpose, the struct `result_of` (see, *e.g.*, [the cplusplus *result_of* reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/result_of/)). Before C++11, instead, the user was supposed to manually define `result_type` (and eventually the argument types) for every adaptable function object, as explained in [the old SGI overview of *function objects*](http://www.martinbroadhurst.com/stl/functors.html). In CGAL, there are algorithms that use structs which have been deprecated or removed from the C++ standard (see [the *CGAL::cpp98* namespace reference](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/STL_Extension/namespaceCGAL_1_1cpp98.html)). The reason you must define the `result_type` is for allowing those algorithms to compile correctly.

Comment: Let's see if I understood: the `result_type` is needed in order to maintain compatibility with code written with versions of C++ previous than C++11. To better clarify this point, you brought as example the case of `CGAL::cpp98::binary_function` that is a struct that takes as template argument  a `result_type` and aims to replace the `std::binary_function` that is deprecated since C++11, and removed from C++17. But my second question remains open: "How can I know which members are required other than those on the documentation?"

Comment: Here is the link to the original [concept](http://www.martinbroadhurst.com/stl/BinaryFunction.html) documentation from SGI website that is now down.

Comment: Thank you for the link, but I still don't see where it says that one user is supposed to define the `result_type`. If I correctly interpreted the documentation, they say that the result type (that in my case is `bool`) must be convertible to `bool`. Further, I don't understand the reason why `Less_xy_2` complains about the missing `result_type` but other predicates do not, included `Less_yx_2`.

Comment: The section `Associated types` refers to nested types that are defined by any model of the concept.

Comment: Thank you for the references. I edited the answer with the additional info of the comments above.